# WinUI 3 set style manually

Tags: c++, xaml, winui-3

In XAML I can have a button style:

```xml
<Button  Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" x:Name="OnStyle"></Button>
<Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" x:Name="OffStyle"></Button>
```

How do I set these in the C++ code?

```cpp
auto b = window.Content().FindName(L"OnStyle").as<Button().Style(...?);
```

This accepts a winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Style (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.style?view=winrt-22621)) but I'm not sure how to set it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="CppExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:CppExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel x:Name="Root">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style
                x:Key="CustomButtonStyle"
                TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button
            x:Name="br_Midi"
            Width="90"
            Margin="0,10,5,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE86F;" />
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="rb_Midi"
                    Text="MIDI" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cpp**

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  auto style = (Style&)Root().Resources().Lookup(box_value(L"CustomButtonStyle"));
  br_Midi().Style(style);
}
```

Comment: Yes. The problem is now that my button which is defined as '<Button x:Name="br_Midi" Margin="0,10,5,0" Width="90"  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE86F;"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="MIDI" x:Name="rb_Midi"/>
                </StackPanel></Button>' fails to find the "rb_Midi" tag.

Comment: Weird. I updated my sample app with the code in your comment, changed "myButton" to "rb_Midi" and still works.